# Unable to resolve own module - Expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, openapi, openapi-generator

I have created my own expo project with pure javascript (not typescript). I generated a javascript Api Client using [OpenApi Generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator).

To integrate the api with my code I need to link that package manually as:

> To use the library locally without publishing to a remote npm registry, first install the dependencies by changing into the directory containing `package.json` (and this README). Let's call this `JAVASCRIPT_CLIENT_DIR`. Then run:
>
> ```sh
> npm install
> ```
>
> Next, [link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) it globally in npm with the following, also from `JAVASCRIPT_CLIENT_DIR`:
>
> ```sh
> npm link
> ```
>
> To use the link you just defined in your project, switch to the directory you want to use your wizard_card_game_api from, and run:
>
> ```sh
> npm link /path/to/<JAVASCRIPT_CLIENT_DIR>
> ```
>
> Finally, you need to build the module:
>
> ```sh
> npm run build
> ```

I managed to see my module in `node_modules` folder.

When I run `expo start` always get:

```
Unable to resolve module wizard-card-game-api from C:\Users\myUser\Documents\Code\React-Native\react-native-wizard-client\client\features\login\actions.js: wizard-card-game-api could not be found within the project.

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:
 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
 2. Delete node_modules and run yarn install
 3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
 4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
```

Btw, I don't have `tsconfig.json` file, since I'm not using typescript.

I have created a type for my module because was suggested by Visual Code. A placed it in the root folder with the name `desc.d.ts`:

```
declare module 'wizard-card-game-api';
```

I have read also: [Expo question](https://forums.expo.io/t/how-to-clear-the-expo-and-react-native-packager-caches-metro-watchman-haste/1352)

Also read about configuration regarding typescript and `tsconfig.json` which I cannot follow.

**package.json**

```json
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.14.7",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^12.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.15.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.11",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.12.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.5",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "expo": "~42.0.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-42.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.4.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "redux": "^4.1.0",
    "redux-immutable-state-invariant": "^2.1.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.6",
    "eslint": "^7.31.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^16.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.23.4",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.24.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

***loginAction.js***

```js
/* tslint:disable */
import WizardCardGameApi from 'wizard-card-game-api';  // <<< --- ERROR HERE

import constants from './constants';

const loginActions = {
  login: (playerName, wizardId) => {
    let api = new WizardCardGameApi.LobbyControllerApi();
    let joinLobbyRequest = new api.JoinLobbyRequest('SlinkmanSorcery', playerName, wizardId);
    let callback = function (error, data, response) {
      if (error) {
        console.error(`Error: ${error}`);
      } else {
        console.log(`API called successfully. Returned data: ${data}`);
      }
    };
    api.joinLobby(joinLobbyRequest, callback);

    return {
      type: constants.LOGIN,
      playerName,
      wizardId,
    };
  },
  logout: () => {
    return {
      type: constants.LOGOUT,
    };
  },
};

export default loginActions;
```

***babel.config.js***

```js
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    env: {
      production: {
        plugins: ['react-native-paper/babel'],
      },
    },
  };
};
```

***Api index.js file***

```js
/**
 * Wizard Card Game API
 * This API drives the Wizard Card Game.
 *
 * The version of the OpenAPI document: 1.0.0
 * Contact: rw.slinkman@gmail.com
 *
 * NOTE: This class is auto generated by OpenAPI Generator (https://openapi-generator.tech).
 * https://openapi-generator.tech
 * Do not edit the class manually.
 *
 */
import ApiClient from './ApiClient';
import CardEntity from './model/CardEntity';
import CreateGameRequest from './model/CreateGameRequest';
/* ... */
import UserRoundStateResponse from './model/UserRoundStateResponse';
import GameControllerApi from './api/GameControllerApi';
import LobbyControllerApi from './api/LobbyControllerApi';

export {
    /**
     * The ApiClient constructor.
     * @property {module:ApiClient}
     */
    ApiClient,

    /**
     * The CardEntity model constructor.
     * @property {module:model/CardEntity}
     */
    CardEntity,

    /**
     * The CreateGameRequest model constructor.
     * @property {module:model/CreateGameRequest}
     */
    CreateGameRequest,

    /**
     * The EstimateRequest model constructor.
     * @property {module:model/EstimateRequest}
     */
    EstimateRequest,

    /* ... */

    /**
    * The GameControllerApi service constructor.
    * @property {module:api/GameControllerApi}
    */
    GameControllerApi,

    /**
    * The LobbyControllerApi service constructor.
    * @property {module:api/LobbyControllerApi}
    */
    LobbyControllerApi
};
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem. Here are the steps I did:

1. Change my api folder to be within *react-native* app.
   [image]
2. Install [babel-plugin-module-resolver](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver)

```sh
expo install babel-plugin-module-resolver
```

3. Create a *.babelrc.json* file in the root of my *client* app:

```json
{
  "presets": ["babel-preset-expo"],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "root": ["./"],
        "alias": {
          "wizard-card-game-api": "./api/WizardApiClient/src"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

5. Stop *expo* app and re-rerun it as:

```sh
expo start -c
```

Now, *loginAction.js* works great:

```js
import WizardCardGameApi from 'wizard-card-game-api';
```

Cheers.

Important resource: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53865634/992347