# Expo - cannot find typescript alias when compiling for web

Tags: react-native, expo, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to export my expo project for the web but when compiling, I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '@/db'

It works fine on Android builds but fails on the web.
I installed `expo` and `react-native-web` packages and added the following config to my babel.config.js but it still doesn't work and I get the same error:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: [
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
      [
        'module-resolver',
        {
          alias: {
            '@/*': './src/*',
          },
        },
      ],
    ],
  };
};
```

Comment: try adding `"root": ["./"]` under `alias` as stated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53865634/16967562) and restart the bundler `yarn start --reset-cache`.